how to make my animation play every 5 seconds
hello guys i im trying to make a lightbulb effect that the text is flickering. but i dont want it to be flicker whole time, i want it to play every 5 sec instead of the whole time.  i tried giving it delay but it only gives me a delay in the begin when de website loads.i use css, tailwindcss and react.js
*{
  color: white;

}
#hero {
  background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}
.navbar {
  background-color: black;
  background: radial-gradient(
    800px circle at var(--mouse-x) var(--mouse-y),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
    transparent 40%
  );
  z-index: 3;
  transition: background 0.1s ease-out;
}

.navbar:hover {
  background: radial-gradient(
    800px circle at var(--mouse-x) var(--mouse-y),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06),
    transparent 40%
  );
}

.navbar > ul>a:first-of-type{
  animation: flicker 2s infinite alternate;
}
.navbar > ul>a:hover{
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #00ffcc,
  0px 0px 20px #00ffcc,
  0px 0px 40px #00ffcc,
  0px 0px 80px #00ffcc;
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0%, 19%, 21%, 23%, 25%, 54%, 56%, 100%{
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #00ffcc,
    0 0 10px #00ffcc,
    0 0 20px #00ffcc,
    0 0 40px #00ffcc,
    0 0 80px #00ffcc;
    ;
  } 20%, 24%, 55%{
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
}
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { IconMoon } from '@tabler/icons-react';

function Navbar() {
  const NavbarContent = [
    "Home",
    "About",
    "Project",
    "Work Experience",
    "Contact",
  ];

  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
    const rect = navbar.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    const y = e.clientY - rect.top;

    navbar.style.setProperty("--mouse-x", `${x}px`);
    navbar.style.setProperty("--mouse-y", `${y}px`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="h-28 items-center flex flex-row-reverse">
      <div
        className="border-white/[0.2] navbar flex max-w-fit fixed inset-x-0 mx-auto border rounded-full px-4 py-2 items-center justify-center space-x-4 z-[5000]"
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
      >
        <ul className="flex justify-between">
          {NavbarContent.map((item, index) =>
            item !== "Contact" ? (
              <Link
                className="relative flex items-center text-sm space-x-1 px-5 opacity-60 hover:opacity-100"
                key={index}
                to={{
                  pathname: `/some/${item}`,
                  search: `?query=${item}`,
                  hash: `#hash`,
                }}
              >
                {item}
              </Link>
            ) : (
              <button
                key={index}
                className="border-white/[0.2] relative border text-sm font-medium px-4 py-2 rounded-full"
              >
                <Link
                  className="relative flex items-center text-sm space-x-1 px-5 opacity-60 hover:opacity-100"
                  to={{
                    pathname: `/some/${item}`,
                    search: `?query=${item}`,
                    hash: `#hash`,
                  }}
                >
                  {item}
                </Link>
                <span className="absolute inset-x-0 w-1/2 mx-auto -bottom-px bg-gradient-to-r from-transparent via-blue-500 to-transparent h-px" />
              </button>
            )
          )}
          <span className="absolute inset-x-0 w-1/2 mx-auto -bottom-px bg-gradient-to-r from-transparent via-green-500 to-transparent h-px" />
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="mr-44 items-center">
        <button className="inline-flex fixed end-20 top-14 items-center justify-center gap-2 whitespace-nowrap rounded-md text-sm font-medium transition-colors focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-1 focus-visible:ring-ring disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:opacity-50 [&_svg]:pointer-events-none [&_svg]:size-4 [&_svg]:shrink-0">
          <IconMoon />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar;


Could you please remove the React, that's entirely unnecessary to a CSS problem; instead, post only the relevant HTML (and the CSS) that the browser receives.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

By flickering every 5s do you mean it looks solidly lit for 5 seconds, then flickers for 2 seconds then goes back to being solidly lit for 5 seconds and so on? If so you have a total animation one pass time of 7 seconds with the flickering occupying just 2/7*100% of the keyframes.

You could increase the animation-duration to 7 seconds, and then calculate how much 5 seconds is of 7 seconds in percentages, and then finally apply that into your animation keyframes:
5 / 7 * 100 = 71.4%


p {
  animation: flicker 7s infinite alternate;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0%, 71.4% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  71.5%, 90%, 92%, 94%, 96%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #00ffcc,
                 0 0 10px #00ffcc,
                 0 0 20px #00ffcc,
                 0 0 40px #00ffcc,
                 0 0 80px #00ffcc;
  }
  90.1%, 95% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
}
<p>Hello World</p>




To add the effect of animation wait/pause for 5s, the easier way is to make your animation 5s longer than the active animation state. This means that rather than animating up to 100% of the keyframe, complete your animation within 16.67% of the keyframe. Now, if you make your animation 6s long, 16.67% of keyframe animation will take 1s to run, and the rest 5s looks like a pause in an animation. For simple example
@keyframes scaling {
  0%,
  16.67% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  8.34% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

.scaling {
  animation: scaling 6s infinite linear;
}

So, in this example, the scaling animation total time is 6s, but the active animation takes only 1s to run as our active animation complete at 16.67% keyframes. Thus when the next cycle of animation runs, it gives the effect of 5 second pause in animation.
Now, use this idea to convert your flicker animation code.
